# Saving and retrieving data from realm database in android

Tags: android, database, realm, crud, realm-mobile-platform

Hi i used realm to save data into relam database but its not saving data to database

In my application class

```
Realm.init(this);
        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().build();
        Realm.deleteRealm(config);
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
```

In my saving activity

```
  public void SaveUserData(final UserData userData, Realm realm)
    {
        final String userdata = new Gson().toJson(userData);
        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
//                realm.createObjectFromJson(com.mediquick.databaseModel.UserData.class, userdata);

                com.mediquick.databaseModel.UserData user = realm.createObject(com.mediquick.databaseModel.UserData.class);
                user.setLname(userData.getLname());
                user.setEmail(userData.getEmail());
                user.setToken(userData.getToken());
                user.setAddress(userData.getAddress());
                user.setMobile_no(userData.getMobile_no());
                user.setDob(userData.getDob());
                user.setName(userData.getName());
                user.setProfile_pic(userData.getProfile_pic());
                user.setUser_type(userData.getUser_type());
            }
        });
```

And when i retrieve a value

```
public String getUserToken(Realm realm)
    {
        final com.mediquick.databaseModel.UserData user = realm.where(com.mediquick.databaseModel.UserData.class).findFirst();
        return  (user!=null)?user.getToken():null;
    }
```

It gives null back when i retrive token from the database

Any ideas..

Comment: I do not know what thread you are calling `getUserToken()` on and when.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce main thread

Comment: in that case this is possible only if `userData.getToken()` is null.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce  when saving i debugged the value is coming fine. May be because i am missing realm.insertOrUpdate its not saving the value, is it necessary for all realm execution ?

Comment: You used `realm.createObject()` which immediately creates managed instance, and `setToken()` will be persisted therefore in the db, so not necessarily.

Comment: Which thread did you call `SaveUserData()` on?

Comment: When i removed the configuration object then everything worked

Comment: @EpicPandaForce is it neccessary to close the realm object after use?

Comment: @GeorgeThomas every `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` call should be paired with a `realm.close()` call, but you can only access managed RealmObjects while at least one Realm instance is open (and not closed).

Answer (score 1):

Declare Realm Object before onCreate function:

```
Realm realmDB;
```

Now write these line in onCreate Method:

```
Realm.init(this);
realmDB=Realm.getDefaultInstance();
```

On save button click method:

```
  try{
         realmDB.beginTransaction();
         UserSchedule us = realmDB.createObject(UserSchedule.class);
         us.setId(userData.get_ID());
         us.setDate(userData.getDate()); 
         realmDB.commitTransaction();
     }
     catch (Exception ex){
           Log.d("RError",ex.toString());
       Toast.makeText(this, "Error in realm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
```

To get records:

```
RealmResults<UserSchedule>userSchedules=realmDB.where(UserSchedule.class).findAll();
        for (UserSchedule userSchedule:userSchedules)
        {
           Toast.makeText(this,userSchedule.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           Toast.makeText(this, userSchedule.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        }
```

To delete record:

```
 RealmResults<UserSchedule> result = realmDB.where(UserSchedule.class).findAll();

UserSchedule userSchedule = result.where().equalTo("Id", getItem(position).getS_ID()).equalTo("Date",getItem(position).getDate()).findFirst();
if(userSchedule!=null)
{

if (!realmDB.isInTransaction()) 
{
    realmDB.beginTransaction();
}
 userSchedule.deleteFromRealm();
 realmDB.commitTransaction();
}
else
{
Toast.makeText(this,"No Record.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this save function:

```
// SAY YES TO THIS
Realm realm = null;
try {                          // I could use try-with-resources here
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            realm.insertOrUpdate(dog);
        }
    });
} finally {
  if(realm != null) {
    realm.close();
  }
}
```

In your code you are missing call

```
realm.insertOrUpdate(user)
```

inside `executeTransaction` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void saveData(){
    realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm bgRealm) {
            Students students = bgRealm.createObject(Students.class);
            students.setName(name.getText().toString().trim());
            students.setCity(city.getText().toString().trim());
            students.setDegree(degree.getText().toString().trim());
            students.setGender(gender.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            // Transaction was a success.
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error) {
            // Transaction failed and was automatically canceled.
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is my save code it save data but my data doesn't show

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.